# Need help identifying shower stem

Tags: shower

Our shower handle recently became wiggly to the sides. The part sitting on the stem/broach seems to be stripped, causing it not to turn the stem when I turn the handle.

However, this stem doesn't show up in any of my searches.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your pictures don't show everything, but check everywhere, including behind the escutcheon and under the spout and showerhead for a maker's mark.  These can all be bought separate from the valve, but it can still give you a hint.  It can be hard to identify shower parts even once you know the manufacturer because of their longevity.  A better picture indicating the part you believe has worn down and a better description of how and what you don't believe is moving as it should would help.

Comment: The last shower valve assembly I had to identify, I knew the manufacturer and used their "website tool" to try to figure out the valve replacement.  The tool just takes the information you have about your valve and directs you to a very expensive list of this year's models.  Not helpful when you're trying to ID a 20 year old valve.  I removed the escutcheon and did visual comparisons of the part inside the wall until I found the right in-wall assembly and I was able to look up the parts I needed from there.  Look in the furnace room in case some smart person saved the manual!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's a Delta shower valve. Matches the one in this link.

http://www.nononsenselandlord.com/2016/01/how-to-fix-a-delta-shower-faucet-leak/

Comment: +1, Absolutely a Delta. That oval shaped stem is hooked to a ball, under the ball there are washers (Delta calls them "seats") with springs under them. Your handle is broken but I recommend you open it up and replace the "seats and springs" while you are at it. Exercise your Google/YouTube kung-fu to see many videos of how to disassemble/assemble and adjust.